# Adding two numbers in linux x86-64 and newline

Tags: assembly, x86-64, att

I'm currently trying to learn assembly language for my study. I figured I would just try with trial and error, but I don't understand enough of assembly for me to be able to do that. I wanted to write a simple program that allowed me to input 2 numbers and than print out the two numbers together, so simply addition.

I tried to start with just trying to input two numbers and than printing those two, but I get the segmentation fault when I enter the second number in.

Another thing I would like to know is why I have to input a number twice in a row when I put "%d\n" instead of "%d". I want to print the numbers of separate lines, but when I try to do so I have to enter the number twice in a row. I would like to know why this happens and how I can fix it.

If this has been asked before, I am sorry. I may have come across that post before, but I find it hard to understand the solutions as well as the code that other people have.

```
.text

    string: .asciz "Your first program\n"
    number1: .asciz "%u"
    number2: .asciz "%d"

.global main

main:

    movq $0, %rax
    movq $string, %rdi
    call printf
    call adding
    call end

adding:

    movq %rsp, %rbp
    subq $8, %rsp
    leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movq $number1, %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call scanf
    popq %rsi
    movq $number1, %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call printf
    movq $0, %rdi
    subq $8, %rsp
    leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movq $number2, %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call scanf
    popq %rsi
    movq $number2, %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call printf
    movq -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    movq -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret

end:

    movq $0, %rdi
    call exit
```

Comment: You're not flushing `stdout` after printing your numbers. Either change the format-string to `"%d\n"/"%u\n"`, or call `fflush(stdout)` after `printf()`. The crash is because you `popq %rsi` after your first `scanf()`, but you don't make space on the stack again before you call `scanf()` the second time.

Comment: So what exactly should I edit/put in than?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some fixes to apply to your program:

```
.text

    string: .asciz "Your first program\n"
    number1in: .asciz "%u"     #use different format strings for input and output
    number2in: .asciz "%d"
    number1out: .asciz "%u\n"  #added "\n" to flush stdout.
    number2out: .asciz "%d\n"  #same

.global main

main:
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $string, %rdi
    push %rbp            #dummy push to satisfy 16-byte alignment requirements
    call printf
    call adding
    call end

adding:
    pushq %rbp           #must preserve %rbp before...
    movq %rsp, %rbp      #...%rbp is overwritten here
    subq $16, %rsp       #must subtract 16 from %rsp to satisfy 16-byte alignment
    leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movq $number1in, %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call scanf
    movq -8(%rbp), %rsi  #this line must be edited...
    movq $number1out, %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call printf
    movq $0, %rdi
    leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movq $number2in, %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call scanf
    movq -8(%rbp), %rsi  #as must this...
    movq $number2out, %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call printf
    movq %rbp, %rsp
    popq %rbp
    ret

end:
    pushq %rbp           #dummy push to satisfy 16-byte alignment
    movq $0, %rdi
    call exit
```

Comment: When/where exactly did you add the 2 numbers together?

Comment: There ought to be a limit to my generosity, especially when you're asking me to do your job. When you ask me how to stop your program from segfaulting, that's fine. Asking me to write it for you, not so much.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean it like that. I am really thankful for your help.